# Install a Python package on QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-3, ubuntu

I have QGIS installed in Ubuntu and I want to install a Python package.
I simply cannot find the QGIS Python console. Where is it located?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For installing python packages for your Ubuntu QGIS-3, you don't need to launch Python Console. First, in bash console:

```
sudo su
[sudo] password for user:
apt-get install python3-pip
pip3 install name_of_desired_package
```

Afterward, you can launch Python Console in QGIS 3 as in following image (where I imported **geopandas** third party python module installed with pip3):

[image]

Comment: I find that this doesn't work for me. If I pip install a package from the terminal (outside QGIS), I am unable to import it within a python script in the QGIS python console. Does QGIS use a different version of Python than the system? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

This appears not to work if you installed via flatpak.  the installed python is not able to recognize my globally installed pycurl.  I have an issue open here

https://github.com/flathub/org.qgis.qgis/issues/67